# error while create paypal sandbox , status is "error"

Tags: paypal, sandbox

i create  lot of sandbox  but  in status it shows me  "error" what is reason ? .

[image: sandbox]

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is caused by some issues with the sandbox system.  For this issue, you would need to file a technical support ticket with PayPal at www.paypal.com/mts